# How to explicitly mention external volume name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation

With the below docker-compose:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  myvolume:
    external: true

networks:
  network1:
    name: my-app-net

services:
  someservice:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - myvolume:/var/folder
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - my-app-net
```

---

Folder `/a/b` already exists on docker host

If I write a random cloudformation task definition with resource type `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition`, then we write something like:

```
  SomeTaskDefinition:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:

        - Name: someapp
          Image: someaccount/someimage
          Memory: 450
          MountPoints:
            - ContainerPath: /var/www/someapp
              SourceVolume: webroot


      Volumes:
        - Name: webroot
          Host:
            SourcePath: /a/b
```

where we don't mention any storage driver option(`--driver`) as we use it in `docker volume create` command, we just mount it.

---

How do I make external volume to be a specific folder(`/a/b`) ext2 FS, available in docker host? that `myvolume` can designate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to mount directory /a/b/ from host, you can use

```
volumes:
  - /a/b/:/var/folder
```

If you want to create a named volume from a directory on the host outside of compose you can use -

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt device=/a/b --opt type=none myvolume
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/

Comment: Yes the above command creates a docker volume based on the directory /a/b. That was your question right?

Comment: It's the stroage driver. 

https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/btrfs-driver/

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/#supported-storage-drivers-per-linux-distribution

Comment: ok, but what are we trying to do with `/a/b`  ext2 filesystem? Using this storage driver

Comment: ok, but why are we converting `/a/b`(ext2 file system) to `btrfs` file system?

Comment: You actually can use `type=none` as you are not mounting a new filesystem. I just used the example used in docs. Edited the answer.

Comment: my question is.... why do we need all these options? `--driver local` and why we do we need to create a volume ? `docker volume create`... please see the cloud formation syntax in my query added

Comment: `--driver local` just means the volume is created on the same host machine. Your question is how to create a named volume from directory /a/b on the host machine and call it `myvolume` right? If you don't need a named volume, you can directly reference the host directory as follows in compose file. 

```
volumes:
      - /a/b:/var/folder
```

Comment: ok this is what I was looking for... can you add this in `volumes: - /a/b:/var/folder` in the answer? with complete docker-compose file taken from query. I will test it later

Comment: Edited the answer. Since you had `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` in the question already, I assumed you knew how to mount specific paths from host machine already.